# How to connect to host via ssh, after successfull connection, run command and get output

Tags: python

1. I try connect to host via ssh subprocess
2. after connection I trying to run command subprocess and get output
3. my script stop on 1 function "main"
4. I can not use paramiko lib

```
import subprocess

host_list = ['host']


def main():
    print("Running latency check")
    for item in host_list:
        host = ''.join(item)
        connect_to_host(host)


def connect_to_host(host):
    print(host)
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-o', 'ConnectionAttempts=3', host], shell=True,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for ssh_line in iter(ssh.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield ssh_line
    ssh.stdout.close()
    get_legend = subprocess.Popen(['command'], shell=True,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for get_legend_line in iter(get_legend.stdout.readline, ""):
        yield get_legend_line
    get_legend.stdout.close()


main()
```

script stop on first function, just print "Running latency check"

Comment: Your `connect_to_host` function uses `yield` and is therefore a generator and not a regular function, but you never iterate over it or call `next()` on it, so essentially execution of it never starts. Regardless of your question, this needs to be fixed first.

Comment: def connect_to_host(host):
    print(host)
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-o', 'ConnectionAttempts=3', host, 'command'],
                           shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    ssh = ssh.communicate()[0]
    for line in ssh:
        print(line)

Comment: This is really unreadable. If you want help, you should at least make sure your questions are readable.